# Spring H2 Table not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm getting an error which can be *relieved* with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` but I don't know why its happening. I need explanation to why its crashing and if the ddl-auto=update is the right fix for it

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
public class Author extends BaseEntity {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book extends BaseEntity{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books")
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private Publisher publisher;
    private String name;
```

```
@Table(name = "publishers")
@Entity
public class Publisher extends BaseEntity{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "publisher")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
```

```
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        Publisher publisher1 = new Publisher("London Book Publishing");
        publisherService.save(publisher1);

        Author author1 = new Author("Mike", "Kelly");
        Author author2 = new Author("Terry", "Jones");
        List<Author> authors = Arrays.asList(author1, author2);

        Book book = new Book("Don Doxuito");

        author1.getBooks().add(book);
        author2.getBooks().add(book);
        book.setPublisher(publisher1);

        authorService.saveAll(authors);
```

```
*application.properties*
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./src/main/resources/data/myDB
spring.datasource.username=sa
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

```
Stacktrace
2022-05-30 20:35:59.311  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] m.github.bookpublishing.BookDatabaseApp  : Starting BookDatabaseApp using Java 11.0.13 on michael-XPS-15-7590 with PID 383839 (/home/michael/Documents/Book-Publishing/target/classes started by michael in /home/michael/Documents/Book-Publishing)
2022-05-30 20:35:59.312  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] m.github.bookpublishing.BookDatabaseApp  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-05-30 20:35:59.352  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-05-30 20:35:59.352  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-05-30 20:35:59.709  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-05-30 20:35:59.734  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 21 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-05-30 20:36:00.040  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-05-30 20:36:00.045  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-05-30 20:36:00.045  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.60]
2022-05-30 20:36:00.078  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-05-30 20:36:00.078  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 726 ms
2022-05-30 20:36:00.096  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-05-30 20:36:00.169  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-05-30 20:36:00.175  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:file:./src/main/resources/data/myDB'
2022-05-30 20:36:00.246  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-05-30 20:36:00.267  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.7.Final
2022-05-30 20:36:00.340  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-05-30 20:36:00.391  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2022-05-30 20:36:00.641  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-05-30 20:36:00.645  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-05-30 20:36:00.818  WARN 383839 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-05-30 20:36:00.909  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2022-05-30 20:36:00.991  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-05-30 20:36:01.010  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-05-30 20:36:01.017  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] m.github.bookpublishing.BookDatabaseApp  : Started BookDatabaseApp in 1.929 seconds (JVM running for 2.347)
2022-05-30 20:36:01.036  WARN 383839 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
2022-05-30 20:36:01.036 ERROR 383839 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "PUBLISHERS" not found; SQL statement:
insert into publishers (id, name) values (default, ?) [42102-200]
2022-05-30 20:36:01.042  INFO 383839 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-05-30 20:36:01.070 ERROR 383839 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    at mikesmikes.github.bookpublishing.BookDatabaseApp.main(BookDatabaseApp.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into publishers (id, name) values (default, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259) ~[spring-orm-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at mikesmikes.github.bookpublishing.services.serviceSDJpaImpls.PublisherServiceImpl.save(PublisherServiceImpl.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at mikesmikes.github.bookpublishing.services.serviceSDJpaImpls.PublisherServiceImpl.save(PublisherServiceImpl.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at mikesmikes.github.bookpublishing.bootstrap.Bootstrap.run(Bootstrap.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:777) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3885) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:637) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "PUBLISHERS" not found; SQL statement:
insert into publishers (id, name) values (default, ?) [42102-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7628) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:7599) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1747) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:954) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:76) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:1154) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:344) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

The physical tables your entities are mapped to need to be created somehow in your DB.

Specifying `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` makes Hibernate auto-generate the tables based on the entities it detects in your project. (Under the hood this property is converted to Hibernate's `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`, its corresponding values are described here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl)

For other ways to initialize DB in Spring Boot see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization

Note that usage of any of the auto generation modes is highly discouraged in production. The proper solution for production DB initialization/migration is tools like Liquibase and Flyway.

Comment: That makes sense because h2 console in the browser was able to find tables where as h2 in intellij couldn't. Learning Liquibase and Flyway soon thanks